# Metaplex JS implementation in React Native: TypeError: Conversion from 'BigInt' to 'number' is not allowed

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, typescript, metaplex-js, react-native

Trying out this package in React Native

RN Version: 0.69.5
Metaplex js version: 0.15.0
@solana/web3.js: 1.41.6

### Error log:

```
TypeError: Conversion from 'BigInt' to 'number' is not allowed. 
App@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.NiftyClick:112134:41
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AppContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.NiftyClick:78237:36
NiftyClick(RootComponent)@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.NiftyClick:84792:28
 ERROR  Error: Requiring module "node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/cjs/index.cjs", which threw an exception: TypeError: Conversion from 'BigInt' to 'number' is not allowed. 
App@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.NiftyClick:112134:41
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AppContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.NiftyClick:78237:36
NiftyClick(RootComponent)@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.NiftyClick:84792:28
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "@metaplex-foundation/js").Metaplex')

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in NiftyClick(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "@metaplex-foundation/js").Metaplex')

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in NiftyClick(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
```

### Steps to repro:

Follow app setup steps from here:
https://solanacookbook.com/integrations/react-native.html#how-to-use-solana-web3-js-in-a-react-native-app

but keep solana web3js version to 1.41.6 (above that it will not work again coz of this BigInt issue)

After this, install https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libs-react-native
to get all the required react native packages
make changes as mentioned in the docs of this package to `metro.config.js`

Once this is complete and if you face RNRandomBytes error as mentioned here: https://github.com/parshap/node-libs-react-native/issues/23
follow the comments to apply patch.

try running the app after this and we receive the BigInt error

## Example:

https://github.com/ritvij14/rn-cli-metaplex

## Edit(10/09/2022):

Tried the updated Solana cookbook. That itself did not work, issue: https://github.com/solana-developers/dapp-scaffold-react-native/issues/4

Comment: Also, the Cookbook that you followed has now been updated with new instructions that should solve this error.

Comment: @steveluscher thanks, I will try out your suggestion.

Comment: @steveluscher hello, actually I am facing this error on trying to run the scaffold.
https://github.com/solana-developers/dapp-scaffold-react-native/issues/4